# есть права на работу в домене,но не являюсь админом домена как дать общий доступ к папке на сервере с клиента?

Tags: сервер, доступ

Имею права на работу в домене, нужно дать юзеру права доступа к папке на сервере, как это можно сделать с компа-клинета?

Comment: Зависит о того, есть ли у вашего пользователя право давать права на эту папку

Comment: Какая ОС используется в загадке?

Comment: от xp до 10ки , а winserver 2008r2